# Connection to MongoDB with Java

Tags: java, mongodb, bson

I am trying to connect my java project to an online mongo database. I faced some issues so I decided to first try to connect on a local mongo DB but I still have the same problem.

I am using the 3 mongodb libraries (driver,driver-async and driver-core), 3.3.0 version and the bson library, 3.2.2 version.

When I launch my 'helloworld example' , copied from here : http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/java-mongodb-hello-world-example/

I have the following errors :

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bson/codecs/IterableCodecProvider
    at com.mongodb.MongoClient.<clinit>(MongoClient.java:84)
    at mainClass.main(mainClass.java:24)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bson.codecs.IterableCodecProvider
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 2 more`

Note : The example code uses a method which is now deprecated, but even by replacing the code with the new version of it (using MongoClient), I still have the same errors.

Comment: change your bson library to 3.2.3 version

Comment: Do you know where I can download it ?

Comment: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/mongodb/. update all thr dependencies to 3.3.0

Answer (score 0):

Solution :

Download the last version of BSON on :
https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/mongodb/bson/
or
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/bson/

The code furnished in the example need to be updated : use MongoClient instead of just Mongo. Insert example code :

```
/**** Connect to MongoDB ****/
        String uri = <URI of your mongo DB>
        MongoClientURI mgURI = new MongoClientURI(uri);
        MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient(mgURI);
        /**** Get database ****/

        MongoDatabase dataBase = mongo.getDatabase("databaseName");
        MongoCollection<Document> userCollection = dataBase.getCollection("CollectionName");
        Document document = new Document();
        document.put("key1", value1);
        document.put("key2", "value2");
        // insert into database
        userCollection.insertOne(document);
```

Thanks to Veeram for his answers :)

Answer (score 0):

This is because of missing required dependency classes for `CodecRegistries` or `CodecRegistry`  in the classpath. To resolve/prevent the issue, instead of adding `mongodb-driver`, `mongodb-driver-core` and `bson` separately, to avoid version conflict and dependency mismanagement prefer the MongoDB Java Driver uber-artifact **`org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver`** containing the legacy driver, the **mongodb-driver**, **mongodb-driver-core**, and **bson**

**For Maven**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.12.10</version>
</dependency>
```

**For Gradle**

```
implementation 'org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:3.12.10'
```